# Why is my code taking so long to run and why are there big changes in its runtime?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

struct IntVector
{
    int N;
    int* dimensions;
    IntVector(int N): N(N)
    {
        dimensions = new int[N];
        for(auto i=0; i<N; i++)
            dimensions[i] = 0;
    }
    IntVector(const IntVector& other) : N(other.N), dimensions(other.dimensions){}
    ~IntVector()
    {
        delete[] dimensions;
    }
    void set(int index, int value)
    {
        dimensions[index] = value;
    }
    void print()
    {
        std::cout << "N: " << N << std::endl;
        for(auto i=0; i<N; i++)
            std::cout <<"dimension[" << i << "] : " << dimensions[i] << std::endl;
    }
    void operator=(const IntVector& other)
    {
        N = other.N;
        dimensions = other.dimensions;
    }
};

int main(){
    int N;
    std::cin >> N;
    auto v1 = IntVector(N);
    for(auto i=0; i<N; i++)
        v1.set(i, i+1);
    auto v2 = IntVector(v1);
    v2.print();
    auto v3 = IntVector(N);
    v3.print();
    v3 = v1;
    v3.print();
    return 0;
}
```

I had a simple homework as above. To briefly explain what the code does, it takes an integer from the user and uses that integer to determine the number of dimensions in the IntVector struct. It dynamically allocates memory as much space as the integer entered by the user.

The interesting part is that when I first run the code, it took less than 1 second to display the parts I printed, but it took around 3 seconds for the code to finish running completely. The more interesting part is that when I run the code for the second time, it took less than 1 second to display the parts I printed again, but this time it took 30 seconds for the code to finish running completely.

(Note: I typed 3 as input while running the code)

I don't understand why this is so, I would appreciate it if you could help, thank you for your answers in advance.

Comment: Here `N` is `3`, then?

Comment: Your second constructor steals a pointer from another object which may become invalidated, leading to undefined behaviour. Tip: Don't use `new[]`, use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: For what it's worth this runs pretty much instantaneously on my machine and crashes due to "pointer being freed was not allocated", which is likely the issue I just pointed out.

Comment: did you compile with optimization? Most IDEs offer preset Debug and Release modes to build and run your code. Probably runtime is more stable in Release build.

Comment: Yep, I ran it in the release mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the [answer given by Anonymous1847](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64486454/10871073), your program exhibits **undefined behaviour** (which can include taking a long time to do something obscure ... sometimes), because you are deleting the allocated pointer multiple times when the three class objects are deleted (immediately before the program exits).

This is because, in your copy constructor, you are simply taking a copy of the allocated pointer, rather than making a (new) copy of the data (and likewise in your assignment operator).

So, your copy constructor should be:

```cpp
    IntVector(const IntVector& other) : N(other.N) {
        dimensions = new int[N];
        for (auto i = 0; i < N; i++)
            dimensions[i] = other.dimensions[i];
    }
```

And similarly for your assignment operator (which should return a reference to a class object, rather than `void`):

```cpp
    IntVector& operator=(const IntVector& other) {
        delete[] dimensions; // First, delete the existing array
        N = other.N;
        dimensions = new int[N]; // Create a new block ...
        for (auto i = 0; i < N; i++) // ... then copy contents.
            dimensions[i] = other.dimensions[i];
        return *this;
    }
```

However, as noted in the comments, you would be far better off using the [`std::vector` container class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) provided by the Standard Library. Here is an implementation of your class using that container (your `main` function need not be changed to use it):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct IntVector {
    std::vector<int> dimensions;
    IntVector(int N) : dimensions(N, 0) { }
    IntVector(const IntVector& other) : dimensions(other.dimensions) {}
    ~IntVector() {}
    void set(int index, int value) {
        dimensions[index] = value;
    }
    void print() {
        std::cout << "N: " << dimensions.size() << std::endl;
        for (auto i = 0u; i < dimensions.size(); i++)
            std::cout << "dimension[" << i << "] : " << dimensions[i] << std::endl;
    }
    IntVector& operator=(const IntVector& other) {
        dimensions = other.dimensions;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Feel free to ask for any further clarification and/or explanation.

Comment: the `operator=` should also delete the allocated old `dimensions`. In the main routine v3 is overridden by v1, causing a destructor of the two deleting an already deallocated array + the original v3 is never deleted

Answer (score 2):

Likely your program is crashing or going through undefined behavior as it exits and executes destructors, which is adding to its run-time. Your `operator=` and default copy constructor is somewhat defective: when you copy, the object being assigned to gets the other object's pointer directly. When these objects (`v1` and `v2` in your case) are destroyed later, they both try to free the same pointer. You want to make your copy constructor and `operator=` allocate new memory and copy the old values over.